# Android studio emulator has no sound

Tags: android-studio

I am coding an Android application with Android Studio running on Windows 10.

```
var swooshSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.introswoosh)
swooshSound.start()
```

Using the MediaPlayer, I am able to hear the sound if I run it on my real Android device but not in my AVD within Android Studio. In fact, I cannot hear any sounds from any virtual emulators I create in Android Studio even the AVD's own ringtones and system sounds. Is there a way to activate sound on AVDs at all?